Python Selenium Traceback (chrome crash and stop):
Code:
options = Options() 
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') 
options.add_argument('--headless') 
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage') 
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.ignore_local_proxy_environment_variables() 
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome' 
chrome_service = Service('/usr/bin/chromedriver') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=options) 
try: 
   driver.get('https://www.google.com') 
   print("Successfully opened Google in headless mode.") 
finally: 
   driver.quit()

Error:
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Firstly, this process is in Ubuntu vps (from hostinger) and also with replit when I run this script it gives me the same problem, I don't think it is the memory since in the vps I have 4GB of ram, I use Selenium 4.21.0 and Chrome 125. I tried updating Chrome and changing versions. I have the same version of chrome and chromedriver, but it still doesn't work, please help ...

in the newest Selenium you can skip service and it may automatically download driver for current browser -  webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Basically I have the error: chrome is no longer running, so chromedriver is assuming that chrome has crashed. For test this problem you can use my code in a repository of replit: https://replit.com/ thanks for reply
